# Standard Template Library, Vectors and Syntax Errors

Tags: c++, vector, stl

This is my first time trying to incorporate STL into my code and I just have a few simple syntax questions I can't seem to figure out.

So I have created a vector of pointers:

```
   std::vector<event_tracking*> track[10];
```

and within a loop in the main program I want to call

```
 track[nfd] = new event_tracking(pfd[nfd].fd, initial_requests);
```

but this line gives the error

```
error: no match for 'operator=' in '((Pds::MyXtcMonitorServer*)this)->Pds::MyXtcMonitorServer::track[nfd] = (((event_tracking*)operator new(12u)), (<anonymous>->event_tracking::event_tracking(((Pds::MyXtcMonitorServer*)this)->Pds::MyXtcMonitorServer::pfd[nfd].pollfd::fd, ((Pds::MyXtcMonitorServer*)this)->Pds::MyXtcMonitorServer::initial_requests), <anonymous>))'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/vector.tcc:133: note: candidates are: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = event_tracking*, _Alloc = std::allocator<event_tracking*>]
```

and later on I want to call a function of my class like:

```
char* p = track[j]->receive_datagram();
```

But I get the error

```
error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::vector<event_tracking*, std::allocator<event_tracking*> >'
```

and then I try to call delete like:

```
delete track[j];
```

and get the error:

```
error: type 'class std::vector<event_tracking*, std::allocator<event_tracking*> >' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer
```

I am really confused because I thought the way to call a function in a class when pointers are involved was by using the -> and I don't understand why that doesn't work here. I also don't understand why the [ ] aren't being used correctly to reference a specific element in the vector. If someone could please explain where my syntax errors are here and why they are arising that would be great! thank you

Comment: The C++ Standard Library and the Standard Template Library [are not the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library#History). Which one are you really talking about?

Comment: You created 10 vectors not a vector of length 10, use ()'s, not []'s

Answer (score 6):

```
std::vector<event_tracking*> track[10];
```

This doesn't create a vector of 10 pointers. It creates an array of 10 empty vectors of pointers. To create a single vector of 10 pointers, use parentheses instead of square brackets.

```
std::vector<event_tracking*> track(10);
```

Comment: Now I get even more errors mainly in regards to <unresolved overloaded function type> Could you explain what that means please?

Comment: @user2616248: It means you are trying to call an overloaded function, but the arguments you providing are either incorrect, or they are ambiguous with regards to the available overloads.